# How to make an imageView change background randomly?

Tags: android, background-image, android-imageview, effects

I have an imageview with 5 backgrounds to choose from. I want to fade image2 out and set image5 as background with fade in effect. This should keep changing randomly. The problem is, how do i do this efficiently?

this is how i give fade in and fade out effects using system animations-

**fade out**

```
  Animation out = AnimationUtils.makeOutAnimation(this, true);
        viewToAnimate.startAnimation(out);
        viewToAnimate.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

**fade in**

```
   Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_in);
        viewToAnimate.startAnimation(in);
        viewToAnimate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

this is how i change my background-

```
search_engine_identifier.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_yahoo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two in xml you can get from [**here**](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/06/android-working-with-xml-animations/) then load them like this.

```
ImageView myImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2); 
Animation myFadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Splash.this, R.anim.fadein)
Animation myFadeOutAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Splash.this, R.anim.fadeout);

int value = 0; // Global Type
btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(value%2 == 0){
                  doFadeOutAnimation();
                 }else{
                  doFadeInAnimation();
                 }
                value ++;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is by using one of Android's View Animator classes, such as ObjectAnimator. Here's what I'm doing:

1) Add the drawable ID's of the images you want to use into an int array.

2) Create ObjectAnimators for the fadeIn and fadeOut animations. You can set the duration of the fade in and fade out to whatever you want.

3) Add an AnimatorListener to the fadeOut ObjectAnimator so that when it finishes, it will set the new image (which is chosen randomly by selecting a random number from the images array) and then it will fade back in with the new image, using the fadeIn ObjectAnimator.

4) Create a runnable and in it's run method, start the fadeOut animation.

5) Call handler.postDelayed on the runnable and use that to decide how long you want each image to stay before fading out.

6) At the end of your Runnable's run method, call handler.postDelayed again so the images will continue to fade in and out, but you should make sure that you have some kind of conditional statement so that you can stop the animation when you need to, which is why I used the boolean "running" so I can set it to false when I need to stop the handler from looping.

```
ImageView mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
boolean running = true;

final int[] images = {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3,
    R.drawable.image4, R.drawable.image5};

final Random random = new Random();
final Handler handler = new Handler();

final ObjectAnimator fadeIn = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mImageView, "alpha", 0f, 1f);
fadeIn.setDuration(1000);

final ObjectAnimator fadeOut = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mImageView, "alpha", 1f, 0f);
fadeOut.setDuration(1000);
fadeOut.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        int rand = random.nextInt(images.length);
        mImageView.setImageResource(images[rand]);
        fadeIn.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

    }
});


Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        fadeOut.start();

        if (running) {
            handler.postDelayed(this, 5000);
        }
    }
};

handler.postDelayed(runnable, 5000);


}
```

This will continuously loop through your selected images (randomly) with fade in/ fade out animations. You can add a few checks to make sure the same image doesn't appear twice in a row, etc.